# How to transfer data from source Kafka cluster to target Kafka cluster using Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

As described in the title, I have a use case where I want to copy data from source Kafka topic (Cloudera Kafka cluster) to destination Kafka topic (AWS MSK Kafka cluster) using Kafka connect framework. I have already gone through some of the available options for e.g. KafkaCat Utility and Mirror Maker 2. But I am curious if there is any such connector available in opensource.

**Links followed:**

Kafkacat: https://rmoff.net/2019/09/29/copying-data-between-kafka-clusters-with-kafkacat/

MirrorMaker: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MirrorMaker 2 is open source, and it does exactly what you're asking

https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/mirror

`kcat` is also open-source, but doesn't exactly scale, and doesn't use Connect framework.